# Best place to grind for the FRLG Pokemon League?

Tags: pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

I've made it to the Pokemon League in FireRed version with my team at level 45 and intend to grind roughly ten levels before going in.

Of course doing so on Victory Road would seem the first stop though I am apparently not allowed to use the VS Seeker in there. Would travelling to another area be more efficient for gaining Exp by doing rematches with trainers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once my Pokémon were at Level 55-ish, I used the VS. Seeker on One Island, on Kindle Road, specifically against Crush Kin Mik and Kia, as well as Black Belts Hugh and Shea. They are right next to the hot spring room (Hugh and Shea are walking back and forth in front of it), allowing you to heal your Pokémon when needed. They give about 1000-1600 EXP per rematch. [[source]](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/918915-pokemon-firered-version/75235162)

Another good place is on Cycling Road. Koffing give a good amount of EXP as well and they are plentiful there. However, there are plenty of Pokémon that know Explosion, so you might want to keep on your toes. [[source]](http://s7.zetaboards.com/Nuzlocke_Forum/single/?p=8964611&t=8842794)

[Other options are available, as well.](https://www.dragonflycave.com/kanto/frlg-vs-seeker#level41) Some might not be available till after the E4, though (specifically those in Four Island and beyond).

Answer (score 0):

I would say you go to route 15, get exp share and use ur strongest pokemon to level up,
the best place to level up is right after route 15, in the grass u can find venonat and gloom which are roughly under level 20 and give a lot of exp.

oh yeah u can find ditto there too in the second patch of grass from the left

Answer (score 0):

The route 15 works well. I checked it. The pokemon with exp share can get a good amount of exp from there quickly. Obviously playing a game without any cheats will take hours but for elite four, it is the only place where you can roughly get 2 to 3 pokemon trainers with thousands of exp.

Answer (score -1):

I reached Indigo Plateau but I caught Zapdos and it is level 52. So when I went in, I realized how much grinding i needed to do. My highest level pokemon is fourteen levels lower the louralie. I think I should at least grind up to level 44 or 45, but since I didn't fight any trainers in victory road I would go there for traning. However, island 1, 2, and 3 are also good grinding spots or you can take your vs seeker to the cycling road for training. In my opinion, there are a few trainers that give over a thousand EXP so I recommend fighting them for good EXP.